# How to migrate deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

As they describe us [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822), the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will deprecated in a while.

I try to refactor the implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with `SecurityFilterChain` due to I want to implement an JWT pattern.
The main consideration which I faced is that the configure in returns void.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), accessTokenExpiredInDays, refreshTokenExpiredInDays, jwtSecret);
    customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
    http
        .csrf().disable();
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .addFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
    http
        .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(jwtSecret), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a custom JWT filter when there is already a built in one i spring security?

Comment: `The main consideration which i faced is that the configure in returns void.` and why is this a problem?

Comment: The reason which i tried to implement custom JWT was the refresh access token.
Also with the  SecurityFilterChain Bean i can't add custom filter as i can see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that Spring Security has built-in support for JWT authentication and there is no need to create a custom filter.
You can find an example provided by the Spring Security team [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login).

However, if you do choose to create a custom filter, the recommended way to configure it is by creating a [custom DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-custom-dsls).
This is the same way that Spring Security does it internally.

I've rewritten your configuration below using a custom DSL.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable();
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/error").permitAll();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/api/token/refresh/**").permitAll();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    // apply the custom DSL which adds the custom filter
    http
        .apply(customDsl());
    http
        .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(jwtSecret), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        CustomAuthenticationFilter filter = 
                new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, accessTokenExpiredInDays, refreshTokenExpiredInDays, jwtSecret);
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.addFilter(filter);
    }

    public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
        return new MyCustomDsl();
    }
}
```

This configuration, as well as other examples, are described in the Spring [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) on migrating away from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: The dependencies are available in the build.gradle file https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/build.gradle